# How to check a website for mobile css markup with HTMLUnit?

Tags: java, css, web, media-queries, htmlunit

I want to use HtmlUnit to check if a website (which is not mine) has css markup for mobile or tablet platforms.

This is what my program should do:

> Input: URL of any website
>
> Output: Does the website have css markup for mobile/tablet platforms? - yes or no

Can you give me a hint on how to accomplish that?

Comment: what you are trying to do is have 3 css stylesheets for desktop, mobile, and tablet. Then check the device and deploy its corresponding stylesheet. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to check other websites, not my own.